# Two web elements that have an identical id act differently. (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to locate several ProgressBars on a page with Selenium in Python. What is troubling me is that, two objects that have excactly a same id act differently.

```
(Pdb) ml.colorbars[2]
<framework.web.base.element.ProgressBar object at 0x250dc50>
(Pdb) ml.colorbars[2].element
#### received nothing here
(Pdb) ml.colorbar_2
<framework.web.base.element.ProgressBar object at 0x250dc50>
(Pdb) ml.colorbar_2.element
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="b2dd0af2-53fb-49fd-8595-6cd50c751f99", element="6a49815e-0188-483e-b451-41ed88f916a0")>
(Pdb) ml.colorbars[2]
<framework.web.base.element.ProgressBar object at 0x250dc50>
(Pdb) ml.colorbars[2].element
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="b2dd0af2-53fb-49fd-8595-6cd50c751f99", element="6a49815e-0188-483e-b451-41ed88f916a0")>
```

Here, `colorbar_2` is the name that I gave to the ProgressBar variable. `colorbars[2]` is the thrid element in the list created to store all bars. It seems that getting the `element` attribute of `colorbar_2` activates the corresponding object in the list.

--- 1st updates ---

Code trials are as below.

```
namespace = locals()
colorbars = []
loc_template = "tr[{}]//div[@class='elWidgets-ProgressBar-bar']"

# instantialization of colorbars
for index in range(bar_num):
    colorbar_locator = ('xpath', loc_template.format(index))
    namespace['colorbar_%s' % index] =  ProgressBar(colorbar_locator)
    colorbars.append( namespace['colorbar_%s' % index] )
```

Now I prefer getting a list `colorbars` containing all colorbars rather than getting attributes specifially named as `colorbar_1`, `colorbar_2`, etc., since the variable names were generated dynamically. However I am not able to get the `element` attribute of `colorbars[0]` in debugging, before I get the `element` of colorbar_0. (Please refer to the debug log on top)

Comment: In Python, many of selenium's attributes are actually properties that do some things under the covers. Not too surprising when a property access performs an action in the underlying webdriver API. I'm not familiar with what a `framework.web.base.element.ProgressBar` object is though.

Comment: So is there a question for us? Update the question with your code trials and relevant _HTML_ please.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for your advice. It's been updated.

Comment: @sytech Thanks sytech. I'll think more about this. `ProgressBar` is just class derived from `webelement`, without any special methods right now.